# Extendscript InDesign CS6: Print using a print preset

Tags: javascript, printing, adobe-indesign, extendscript, preset

This one should be simple enough for you Javascript/Extendscript wizards.  I want to print a document using a print preset, while also specifying a page range (and maybe other options as well, after having chosen the preset).  Consulting the InDesign CS6 JavaScript Scripting Guide it has this wonderful, detailed explanation of how to do it:

> Printing with printer presets
>
> To print a document using a printer preset, include the printer preset in the print command.

Wow.  So descriptive and helpful.  Um, can anyone help me make better sense of this?

---

**Edit (01/21/2019)**

I was asked how I was able to tell the script which pages I wanted to print. It turns out that this is not stored in the `PrinterPreset`.

[`Document`](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign13/#Document.html) has a property called `printPreferences` which allows access to the [`PrintPreference`](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign13/#PrintPreference.html) object. This object allows the developer to set the `pageRange` by either specifying a `PageRange` enum or a String with the page range (with "1" being the first page).

So, to illustrate:

```
var document = app.activeDocument; // Presumes the document you want to print is already open.

document.printPreferences.pageRange = PageRange.ALL_PAGES; // Will print all pages in the document.
document.printPreferences.pageRange = "1-3,7,10,12-15" // Prints pages 1, 2, 3, 7, 10, 12, 13, 14, and 15.
```

> *Note:* `PageRange.SELECTED_ITEMS` seems to only be used for exporting items, not printing (since the `PageRange` enum is used for both
>   operations). I have not tested this, however.

There are many other [`PrintPreference`](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign13/#PrintPreference.html) properties that can be set before `document.print()` is called, so it's worth [looking them up](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign13/#PrintPreference.html).

Comment: And how did you eventually tell it the range of pages to print? I do not see this in the answer below. Is it in your printerPresets? Could you show here (by givin an example) how this is done?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I hope that helps. ☺️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `app.print()` method can take a `PrinterPreset` object as one of it's arguments. Here's a [link](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Application.html#print) to a reference of the method for more information.

Here's an example (untested):

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var file = File(doc.fullName);      // Get the active document's file object

var preset = app.printerPresets[0]; // Use your printer preset object

app.print(file, null, preset);
```

The InDesign reference lists the `app.print()` method more or less like this:

```
void print (from: varies[, printDialog: bool][, using: varies])
Prints the specified file(s).

Parameter    Type                Description
from         Array of Files      One or more file paths. Can accept: File or Array of Files.
             File
printDialog  bool                Whether to invoke the print dialog (Optional)
using        PrinterPreset       Printer preset to use. Can accept: PrinterPresetTypes enumerator or PrinterPreset. (Optional)
             PrinterPresetTypes
```

The first information listed is the return value of the method, `void`, in this case which means it doesn't return anything.

The next information listed is the name of the method `print` followed by it's named parameters: `from`, `printDialog`, and `using` as well as what each parameter type should be.

The parameters are also listed in the chart for further explanation. The `from` parameter expects an object of type `File` for example. So, in the example above, I make an "instance" of a `File` object by calling it's constructor: `var file = File(doc.fullName);`. Then I get an already existing `PrinterPreset` object: `var preset = app.printerPresets[0];`. Finally, I pass each object to the function inserting `null` for the middle variable (since it's optional, I just decide to ignore it): `app.print(file, null, preset);`.

Comment: So, you wouldn't use `app.documents.item(0).print()` in place of `app.print()`?  It just seems that would keep me from having to declare those first two variables and just print the currently open document.

Comment: Probably doesn't make a difference either way. Whatever works best for you.

Comment: Excellent.  Now all I need is a reference for all the possible arguments/parameters that `.print()` can take.  Got any good leads?  And if you're going to refer me to Jongware's site, I'm already aware of it, but can't find any good information about such arguments.  Unless, of course, I just don't know how to read a DOM, which is pretty much true.

Comment: I added a little bit of reference explanation, hopefully that helps a bit.

Comment: Fascinating.  It doesn't really allow for all of the possible options in the Print dialog.  Where is this "InDesign reference" of which you speak?  I'd like to study it some myself, if you don't mind.